# Email notification about each SSH connection to Linux server

Tags: linux, security, ssh, email

I would like to be notified about each SSH connection to the Linux (Debian) server.

Already saw some methods, which proposed to add mail command into own .bashrc, but this approach seems not to cover all possible cases.

What is the best practice to make such transversal notifications about SSH connections ?

Comment: How soon after the connection do you want to know?  Do you want a daily report, or do you want an instantaneous e-mail?

Comment: Define at what stage? TCP SYN, full handshake, auth / protocol / key negotiation, auth attempt, etc.?

Comment: @EightBitTony Both. 1.An instant email with IP/username. 2. Daily statistics about connection duration of each user, who was connected.

Comment: @JeffFerland This question is only about successful connections. Of course, an additional protection about each not-successful auth attempt should be configured.

Answer (score 10):

Since you clarified that you want an email for each **successful** authentication, [pam_notify](http://www.svitanok.si/projects/pam_notify/) is a great candidate module for this.

Add it as a `session required` line at the end of your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` or equivalent file.

Answer (score 7):

The best practice is don't unless you ***REALLY*** have to (the security of this machine is THAT critical).

If you ***REALLY*** have to, you don't want to muck about with shell .rc files that people can change - that's a half-baked solution.

The Right Way is probably to use the audit facilities built into Linux (see the man pages for [`auditd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd), and its configuration file [`auditd.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd.conf)), but I have very limited experience with the audit facilities in Linux (in particular I'm not sure the audit subsystem makes it easy to send emails -- I know you can on FreeBSD without too much trouble though).

The less-right-but-still-decent way would be to use a PAM module that always succeeds and kicks out an email saying who tried to log in.

The least-right-but-at-least-your-inbox-isnt-full way would be to batch up your `auth.log` file or equivalent and email it to someone every night.  If all you need is a basic record this would be my choice: The volume of email generated from my other suggestions would be heinous on a system with lots of activity.

Comment: Note per Jeff's comment there are lots of places you can audit the connection if you use the audit facilities -- right down to "attempted TCP connections to port 22", which would generate heinous amounts of audit data for *any* machine connected to the internet...

Answer (score 4):

you can monitor your /var/log/auth.log periodically or even better make it remote logging so attacker cannot wipe out the trace of successful logging in.

Comment: I tried `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd`, but it gives too much data, if there is a short way to make the data preprocessing, to make the data more readable ?

Comment: @Fedir you can try something like this: http://code.google.com/p/linscripts/wiki/logmon

Answer (score 3):

Since this question has been brought up from the vaults, my inclination would be to run [swatch](http://swatch.sourceforge.net/) against `/var/log/auth.log` (or your distro / syslog config's appropriate file), and configure it to respond with an email to each occurrence of `sshd.*Accepted.*`, since this should catch both password-based and key-based logins:

```
Feb 21 10:06:44 lory sshd[24414]: Accepted publickey for username from ::1 port 39197 ssh2
Feb 21 10:08:16 bill sshd[20643]: Accepted password for username from ::1 port 46835 ssh2
```

which you could do with a config file saying, e.g.,

```
watchfor /sshd.*Accepted.*/
               mail address=you@example.com,subject="SSH login on host foo"
```

and e.g. `swatch -c /the/above/file /var/log/auth`.

Answer (score 2):

```
We do it by creating a file /etc/profile.d/notify.sh with the following content:

#!/bin/sh

sender="hostname@example.com"
recepient="admingroup@example.com"
subject="Privileged Account logon used"
message="`env`"
    echo "$message" | mail -s "$subject" -r "$sender" -S smtp=mail.example.com "$recepient"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed my own solution for this problem, which involves monitoring log-files for different services (sshd included), and notifying a single e-mail when certain users gain access to certain services.

I call it Authentication Monitor and you can find more information about it here: http://bwyan.dk/?p=1744

I hope this could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I published a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/ElliotNB/04211e61efe6106b01ff223e5f123257) on Github Gist that does what you're looking for. It will email the system administrator anytime a user logs in from a new IP address. I use the script scrutinize logins on our tightly controlled production systems. If a login is compromised, we'd get notified about the unusual login location and have a chance to lock them out of the system before they cause serious damage.

To install the script, just update it with your sysadmin email, and copy it into `/etc/profile.d/`.