# How can I configure my server to notify me whenever it is remotely accessed via ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, email

I need to be notified by email when my Ubuntu server is accessed via SSH.

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/395393/email-notification-about-each-ssh-connection-to-linux-server?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

[pam_script](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_script) will run any program you want when a user logs in.

Comment: Just a note: if you're still on Lucid you'll have to compile pam_script yourself (it was included with Oneiric)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do so with a rule in `/etc/hosts.allow`.  Try something like:

```
sshd: ALL: (/usr/bin/echo "SSH connection from %h (%H)" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "SSH Alert" you@example.com)
```

You can get more detail from a script run from `/etc/profile.d`, or included in `/etc/profile`.   However, this will only work if the user logs in to an interactive session.

If you don't need immediate notification, the `logcheck` program can notify you hourly of any accesses in the last hour.  You will need to add appropriate rules to the configuration.

EDIT:  Ubuntu uses the incompatible `hosts_options` format to execute shell commands.  The follow rule is what I implemented:

```
SSHD: ALL: spawn (/bin/echo "SSH connection to %H from %h[%a]" | \
     /usr/bin/mailx -s "SSH Alert" me@example.com)
```

Notes: Backslash notation can be used to wrap lines as above.  Substitution characters are documented in the `hosts.allow` man page.

Comment: I'm getting `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` error after setting this. Commenting it out in `/etc/hosts.allow` makes it work again.

Comment: @MHK What happens if you run the commands in brackets at the command line?

Comment: That sends a mail, I had to change `/usr/bin/echo` to `/bin/echo` though on my system. I've disabled root login and password based login via ssh, changed port, watching it with Fail2ban. Other than that, it's a typical Ubuntu 12.04 server edition.

Comment: You will need to change your command in `/etc/hosts.allow` accordingly.

Comment: I did that before posting the error message here.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to set up a script to watch the log file.

I'm on my phone at the moment, but Check /var/log/access.log

Comment: I'm using [swatch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=swatch)

Comment: would you care to complete your answer now that you have probably had access to your desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

The log is on auth.log, you can do a

```
cat /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
```

To actualy send the mail you could install SSMTP, edit it's config as follows:

> /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
>
> root=yourusername@gmail.com
>   mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
>   rewriteDomain=gmail.com
>   AuthUser=yourusername
>   AuthPass=yourpassword
>   FromLineOverride=YES
>   UseTLS=YES

Create a text file with the message body as follows:

> To: recipient@gmail.com
>   From: yourusername@gmail.com
>   Subject: SSH warning or whatever
>
> MAIL CONTENT

To add the content you could do:

```
tail /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh >> /tmp/mailcontents.txt
```

and then run

```
ssmtp recipient_name@gmail.com < /tmp/mailcontents.txt
```

---

EDIT:

Another OP said you might want a notification each time it happens, you coud do something LIKE this:

create an script with

```
!/bin/sh

tail /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh >> /tmp/alert&

while true; do
   change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create .)
   change=${change#./ * }
   if [ "$change" = "/tmp/alert" ]; then 
       tail -n 1 /tmp/alert >> /tmp/mailcontents.txt
       ssmtp recipient_name@gmail.com < mailcontents.txt; 
   fi
done
```

Mailcontents should include the addresses as stated before, the script code has not been checked to be valid, consider it pseudocode.

Comment: I think the OP wants to be notified when events occur, not create a custom report once.

Comment: well same principle, he'd just need to tail /var/log/auth.log permanently with the -f switch as in tail -f --follow=name /var/log/auth.log >> /tmp/alert.log, then he can use inotifywait to track changes in the alert file.

Comment: I failed to use ssmtp. It can connect to gmail server but said the authentication fails while using the same email & password I can log in. Do you have any idea why?
The error is
`ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 nh8sm37308607pbc.60)`

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: @Andres Yes I did. But still the authentication still fails